# Robot - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, awt, awtrobot

I'm trying to create an object of the Robot Class. However, I'm getting ' java.lang.NullPointerException' when trying to do the same.

```
static Robot robot = null;

try {
            robot = new Robot();
            if(keyAction.equals("TABPRESS")){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);                
            }else if(keyAction.equals("TABRELEASE")){
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);                  
            }

}catch(AWTException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can you please suggest how to handle this? This code was functioning properly earlier.

Comment: On which line does the exception occur? Where does `keyAction` come from?

Comment: try debug it, and find which object is null

Answer (score 2):

Although you have not sent the code that creates `keyAction` this is the only thing that can cause NPE in this code fragment. Check it first.

Moreover the better practice to call `equals()` method is to call it on constant and pass other object as a parameter. This is null-safe:

```
        if("TABPRESS".equals(keyAction)){
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);                
        }else if("TABRELEASE".equals(keyAction)){
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);                  
        }
```

Comment: I have validated the variable 'keyAction' is not null. So I'm certain about the fact that the Exception is thrown while creating the object of the Robot class.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. It was not because of any programming issue. Actually, there was a clash of Jre Versions on my system. I uninstalled/deleted all the jdks and installed a new one and everything started working fine.

Thanks, Shreyas.